# FTP Transfer using Terminal (In C)

Tags: c, bash, ftp, zip, corrupt-data

I was working on a simple application that zips a folder and upload it in my website. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Global variables

//Zips the sample_folder and saves the zip file in Library.    
char zip[60] = "cd ~/Library/\nzip -r STORAGE_DATA.zip ~/Desktop/sample_folder/";

//FTPs the file STORAGE_DATA.zip in myhost.com (using myusername and mypassword)
char ftp_transf[150] = "ftp -n myhost.com <<END_SCRIPT\nquote binary\n"
                       "quote USER myusername\nquote PASS mypassword\n"
                       "put ~/Library/STORAGE_DATA.zip STORAGE_DATA.zip";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    system(zip); //Executes first shell script
    system(ftp_transf); //Executes second shell script

    return 0;
}
```

Hope the code is readable and you have understood it. Basically I'm using Terminal commands to zip a folder and upload it in the web. (Please don't tell me how to use C/C++ libraries for FTP, because I need no external libraries)

Ok, the code works fine and the file is uploaded. The problem is...

> When I download the file back from the site and try to open it, the file is corrupted.

Yep, that is the problem... I really cannot understand why! I use binary mode (which is also used by default in FTP), so please... I need some help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the ZIP file that's created locally (before FTPing) not corrupt?  I'm a little wary of your "\n" in the first system command. Perhaps try "cd ~/Library/ && zip -r ...".  Also, it's interesting you can't use "external libraries" but can depend on external binaries which may or may not be present on your target machine.

Comment: Yes, the ZIP file in local is **NOT** corrupted... ALso, I've tried && but it's not working.

Comment: Did/Can you verify the file **on the remote host**? How are you downloading the file back? with a tool, or with the same code as above? Good luck.

Comment: Well, I'm downloading the file back simply by visiting the URL (Ex. http://www.mydomain.com/file.zip) the browser (I'm using Chrome) download it automatically.

Comment: The compiler can count better than you can; don't bother specifying the sizes of the initialized arrays.

Comment: How do you know that the upload did not corrupt the file?  What code are you using to download the file that was uploaded?

Comment: Well, I tried to FTP the file manually, and it **worked!**

Comment: What did you try manually: the upload, or the download? And what are the sizes of the ZIP files a) before the upload, b) on the web host, c) after the download?